# how to call an activity class in onBackPressed()-android

Tags: android

```
public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(this,xxxxx.class);
        startActivity(setIntent); 
        return;
    }
```

I call `onBackPressed()` to one activity the processing happen well.but it call same activity once again (ie) If we press back in android phone the previous onCreate() method can not call in normal action,if we overwrite 'onBackPressed()' onCreate() is called as per the code above. So how we start the activity without help of onCreate().

Comment: Just don't override this method for normal back action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the answer for the above question. Use Activity group to hold the switching class and decrement one value (one Activity) while back is pressed. The below is useful to you:

**Switch from one Activity to another Activity**

Create Arraylist history while switch from one activity to another add that particular view to history

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager()
  .startActivity(
    getString(R.string.hometab), 
    new Intent(this, Sample.class)
      .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)
  ).getDecorView();
FinderActivityGroup.finderGroup.replaceView(view);
```

**On back pressed**

when back pressed the decrease(minus) the history as code below

```
if (history.size() > 0) {
  history.remove(history.size() - 1);
  setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
}
else {
  finish();
}
return;
```

We are decrease the history which means the `onCreate()` method can not call once again which was act like normal back pressed.

Comment: this is copy/paste artistry without link to original source. One such place - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926265/android-tab-navigation

Answer (score 0):

Before `return` you can call `finish();`. And/or instead of `return` call `super.onBackPressed();`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:
just add finish(); insted of return;
this will not let the stack accumulate.

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(this,xxxxx.class);
    startActivity(setIntent); 
    finish();
}
```